# Pomodoro Timer via setTimeout()

Tags: javascript, jquery, event-handling, timer

I've made my attempt to code timer entirely by hand using jQuery. No external libraries to manage time at all.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
 var setSessionMinutes = 5,
  setBreakMinutes = 5,
  sessionMinutes = setSessionMinutes,
  breakMinutes = setBreakMinutes,
  counterSeconds = -1,
  countTimeout,
  runState = false;

 function setClockValues() {
  $('#break').html(setBreakMinutes);
  $('#session').html(setSessionMinutes);
  $('#time').html(formatTime(setSessionMinutes, 0));
  sessionMinutes = setSessionMinutes;
  breakMinutes = setBreakMinutes;
  counterSeconds = -1;
 };
 setClockValues();

 function formatTime(minutes, seconds) {
  minutes = minutes >= 10 ? minutes : '0' + minutes;
  seconds = seconds >= 10 ? seconds : '0' + seconds;
  return minutes + ':' + seconds;
 }

 //change values by buttons
 $('#minusbreak').click(function() {
  $('#break').html(setBreakMinutes > 0 ? --setBreakMinutes : 0);
  breakMinutes = setBreakMinutes;
 });
 $('#plusbreak').click(function() {
  $('#break').html(++setBreakMinutes);
  breakMinutes = setBreakMinutes;
 });
 $('#minusSession').click(function() {
  $('#session').html(setSessionMinutes > 0 ? --setSessionMinutes : 0);
  $('#time').html(formatTime(setSessionMinutes, 0));
  sessionMinutes = setSessionMinutes;
 });
 $('#plusSession').click(function() {
  $('#session').html(++setSessionMinutes);
  $('#time').html(formatTime(setSessionMinutes, 0));
  sessionMinutes = setSessionMinutes;
 });

 function countDown() {
  if (counterSeconds < 0 && sessionMinutes >= 0) {
   --sessionMinutes;
   counterSeconds = 59;
  }
  $('#time').html(formatTime(sessionMinutes, counterSeconds));
  --counterSeconds;
  if (counterSeconds >= 0 && sessionMinutes >= 0)
   countTimeout = setTimeout(countDown, 1000);
  else {
   $('#finish').get(0).play();
   setTimeout(countDownBreak, 1000);
  }
 }

 function countDownBreak() {
  if (counterSeconds < 0 && breakMinutes >= 0) {
   --breakMinutes;
   counterSeconds = 59;
  }
  $('#time').html(formatTime(breakMinutes, counterSeconds));
  --counterSeconds;
  if (counterSeconds >= 0 && breakMinutes >= 0)
   countTimeout = setTimeout(countDownBreak, 1000);
  else {
   stopCountDown();
   $('#status').html('start');
   runState = false;
   $('#finish').get(0).play();
  }
 }
 function stopCountDown() {
  clearTimeout(countTimeout);
  setClockValues();
 }

 //   start/stop timer
 $('#status').click(function() {
  switch (runState) {
   case false:
    $('#status').html('reset');
    countDown();
    runState = true;
    break;
   case true:
    $('#status').html('start');
    stopCountDown();
    runState = false;
    break;
  }
 });

});
```

You can also see it on [CodePen.io](http://codepen.io/ketus/pen/wKjrGw).

I realise this code should be 3/4 or even half current length, more DRY etc., but I'd like to get some opinions about code without much optimization to know better where I currently am with my progress. After all, I could spend 12 hours to make it beautiful (which I eventually will), but that would destroy purpose of this post.

About `setTimeout` instead of `setInterval`: I did it on purpose because of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6685414/3972894).

Answer (score 1):

### Feedback

I know it has been nearly 3 years since this was posted and you likely have learned more about javascript and jQuery since then. Perhaps the information below is old news but nevertheless...

I like the styles and the sound that plays when the timer is done is fun! I did notice that if I decrease the Session Length to `0` and click the start button, it shows `-01:59` and then appears to jump up to `05:58`. Perhaps it would be wise to not allow the user to click the start button if the value for session length is 0.

### Recommendations

I only see a couple things I would change:

- It is recommended that DOM elements be stored in a variable - e.g.

  ```
  var breakElement = $('#break');
  ```

  And then later on use `breakElement` instead of `$('#break')` - e.g.

  ```
  breakElement.html(setBreakMinutes);
  ```
- The `switch` statement at the end seems a bit heavy - why not just use an `if`/`else`:

  > ```
  > switch (runState) {
  >         case false:
  >             $('#status').html('reset');
  >             countDown();
  >             runState = true;
  >             break;
  >         case true:
  >             $('#status').html('start');
  >             stopCountDown();
  >             runState = false;
  >             break;
  >     }
  > ```

  While it is only few lines shorter, there is no need to remember the `break` statements:

  ```
  if (runState) {
      $('#status').html('start');
      stopCountDown();
      runState = false;
  }
  else {
      $('#status').html('reset');
      countDown();
      runState = true;
  }
  ```